# Obj-C UIDownpicker will fill another textfield with another value during scrolls

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, uipickerview

My code below will fetch country name and country code from server and store into `2 NSMutablleMArray`, `countryMArray` and `codeMArray`code. When user tap the `txtCountry UITextField` It will call a `down picker` and when user select the country and hit Done, it will based on index and get the `Country Code from codeMArray` and put the code in `txtCode UITexField`.

Instead of this way, I was wondering how to straight away fill `txtCode UITextfield` when scrolling the `down picker`. Something like the pic below. Instead of getting the user to hit done. When user scrolls the `down picker Country Name` the `txtCode UITexField` will be autofilled with the `Code`. Is there ways to do that.

## Added the following code in *

I added downpicker.m and downpicker.h and also the code in * but it never triggers. Please help, thank you.

[image: When scroll to Malaysia auto fill txtCode with Malaysia Country Code]

[image: When scroll to China auto fill txtCode with China Country Code]

## RootViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "LoginViewController.h"
#import <DownPicker/UIDownPicker.h>

@protocol LoginViewProtocol <NSObject>

- (void)dismissAndLoginView;

@end

@interface RootViewController : UIViewController     <UITextFieldDelegate,UITableViewDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtCountry;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDownPicker *downCountry;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtCode;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtPhone;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *countryMArray;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *codeMArray;
@property (nonatomic) DownPicker *pickerCountry;

@end
```

## RootViewController.m

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface RootViewController (){
    NSString *sURL,*sResponseData, *sRemaining;
    NSString *sCode;

}
@end

@implementation RootViewController

@synthesize loginView;
@synthesize txtCountry,txtCode,txtPhone;
@synthesize countryMArray;
@synthesize codeMArray;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];

    //=== Initiallize the Mutable Array
    countryMArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    codeMArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //=== Initialize the responseData Mutable Data
    self.responseData = [NSMutableData data];

    //=== Pass the string to server to get the return Country response.write
    appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    sURL = @"https://www.share-fitness.com";
    sURL = [sURL stringByAppendingString:@"/apps/getcountry.asp?"];

    NSURLRequest *requestCountry = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:sURL]];

    (void) [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:requestCountry delegate:self];

    //=== Pass the string to server to get the return CountryCode
    sURL = @"https://www.share-fitness.com";
    sURL = [sURL stringByAppendingString:@"/apps/getctcode.asp?"];

    NSURLRequest *requestCode = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:sURL]];

    (void) [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:requestCode delegate:self];

    //=== Initialie the picker ====
    self.pickerCountry = [[DownPicker alloc] initWithTextField:self.txtCountry withData:countryMArray];

    [self.pickerCountry addTarget:self
                       action:@selector(pickerClicked:)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

}

//**** ADDED the following but will never trigger ?
 - (void)pickerView:(UIDownPicker *)pickerCountry didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    sCode = [codeMArray objectAtIndex:row];
    txtCode.text = [@"+"stringByAppendingString:sCode];
}
//**********************
 //=== Pick the countryCode, when Country is selected based on Array Index
 -(void)pickerClicked:(id)dp {

    NSString* selectedValue = [self.pickerCountry text];

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < countryMArray.count; i++) {

        NSString*item = [countryMArray objectAtIndex:i];

        if([item isEqualToString:selectedValue])
        {
            sCode = [codeMArray objectAtIndex:i];
            txtCode.text = [@"+"stringByAppendingString:sCode];

            break;
        }

    }
}
```

## Downpicker.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DownPicker : UIControl<UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    UIPickerView* pickerView;
    IBOutlet UITextField* textField;
    NSArray* dataArray;
    NSString* placeholder;
    NSString* placeholderWhileSelecting;
    NSString* toolbarDoneButtonText;
    NSString* toolbarCancelButtonText;
    UIBarStyle toolbarStyle;
}

@property (nonatomic) NSString* text;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger selectedIndex;

-(id)initWithTextField:(UITextField *)tf;
-(id)initWithTextField:(UITextField *)tf withData:(NSArray*) data;

@property (nonatomic) BOOL shouldDisplayCancelButton;

/**
Sets an alternative image to be show to the right part of the textbox (assuming that showArrowImage is set to TRUE).
 @param image
 A valid UIImage
*/
-(void) setArrowImage:(UIImage*)image;

-(void) setData:(NSArray*) data;
-(void) setPlaceholder:(NSString*)str;
-(void) setPlaceholderWhileSelecting:(NSString*)str;
-(void) setAttributedPlaceholder:(NSAttributedString *)attributedString;
-(void) setToolbarDoneButtonText:(NSString*)str;
-(void) setToolbarCancelButtonText:(NSString*)str;
-(void) setToolbarStyle:(UIBarStyle)style;

/**
 TRUE to show the rightmost arrow image, FALSE to hide it.
 @param b
 TRUE to show the rightmost arrow image, FALSE to hide it.
*/
-(void) showArrowImage:(BOOL)b;

-(UIPickerView*) getPickerView;
-(UITextField*) getTextField;

/**
Retrieves the string value at the specified index.
@return
The value at the given index or NIL if nothing has been selected yet.
*/
-(NSString*) getValueAtIndex:(NSInteger)index;

/**
Sets the zero-based index of the selected item: -1 can be used to clear        selection.
@return
The value at the given index or NIL if nothing has been selected yet.
*/
-(void) setValueAtIndex:(NSInteger)index;
@end
```

## Downpicker.m

```
#import "DownPicker.h"

@implementation DownPicker
{
    NSString* _previousSelectedString;
}

-(id)initWithTextField:(UITextField *)tf
{
    return [self initWithTextField:tf withData:nil];
}

-(id)initWithTextField:(UITextField *)tf withData:(NSArray*) data
{
     self = [super init];
     if (self) {
        self->textField = tf;
        self->textField.delegate = self;

        // set UI defaults
        self->toolbarStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;

        // set language defaults
        self->placeholder = @"Tap to choose...";
        self->placeholderWhileSelecting = @"Pick an option...";
        self->toolbarDoneButtonText = @"Done";
        self->toolbarCancelButtonText = @"Cancel";

        // hide the caret and its blinking
        [[textField valueForKey:@"textInputTraits"]
         setValue:[UIColor clearColor]
         forKey:@"insertionPointColor"];

        // set the placeholder
        self->textField.placeholder = self->placeholder;

        // setup the arrow image
        UIImage* img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"downArrow.png"];   // non-CocoaPods
        if (img == nil) img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DownPicker.bundle/downArrow.png"]; // CocoaPods
        if (img != nil) self->textField.rightView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
        self->textField.rightView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        self->textField.rightView.clipsToBounds = YES;

        // show the arrow image by default
        [self showArrowImage:YES];

        // set the data array (if present)
        if (data != nil) {
            [self setData: data];
        }

        self.shouldDisplayCancelButton = YES;
    }
    return self;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView;
{
    return 1;
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    self->textField.text = [dataArray objectAtIndex:row];
}

 - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component;
 {
    return [dataArray count];
 }

 - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component;
 {
    return [dataArray objectAtIndex:row];
 }

 -(void)doneClicked:(id) sender
 {
    //hides the pickerView
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    if (self->textField.text.length == 0 || ![self->dataArray containsObject:self->textField.text]) {
        // self->textField.text = [dataArray objectAtIndex:0];
        [self setValueAtIndex:-1];
        self->textField.placeholder = self->placeholder;
    }
    /*
    else {
        if (![self->textField.text isEqualToString:_previousSelectedString])   {
            [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        }
    }
    */
    [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}

-(void)cancelClicked:(id)sender
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder]; //hides the pickerView
    if (_previousSelectedString.length == 0 || ![self->dataArray containsObject:_previousSelectedString]) {
        self->textField.placeholder = self->placeholder;
    }
    self->textField.text = _previousSelectedString;
}

- (IBAction)showPicker:(id)sender
{
    _previousSelectedString = self->textField.text;

    pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    pickerView.dataSource = self;
    pickerView.delegate = self;

    //If the text field is empty show the place holder otherwise show the last selected option
    if (self->textField.text.length == 0 || ![self->dataArray containsObject:self->textField.text])
    {
        if (self->placeholderWhileSelecting) {
            self->textField.placeholder = self->placeholderWhileSelecting;
        }
         // 0.1.31 patch: auto-select first item: it basically makes placeholderWhileSelecting useless, but
         // it solves the "first item cannot be selected" bug due to how the pickerView works.
        [self setSelectedIndex:0];
    }
     else
    {
        if ([self->dataArray containsObject:self->textField.text]) {
            [self->pickerView selectRow:[self->dataArray indexOfObject:self->textField.text] inComponent:0 animated:YES];
        }
    }

    UIToolbar* toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
    toolbar.barStyle = self->toolbarStyle;
    [toolbar sizeToFit];

    //space between buttons
    UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                                               target:nil
                                                                               action:nil];

    UIBarButtonItem* doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                               initWithTitle:self->toolbarDoneButtonText
                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                               target:self
                               action:@selector(doneClicked:)];

    if (self.shouldDisplayCancelButton) {
        UIBarButtonItem* cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                     initWithTitle:self->toolbarCancelButtonText
                                     style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                     target:self
                                     action:@selector(cancelClicked:)];

        [toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:cancelButton, flexibleSpace, doneButton, nil]];
    } else {
        [toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexibleSpace, doneButton, nil]];
    }

    //custom input view
    textField.inputView = pickerView;
    textField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar;  
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)aTextField
{
    if ([self->dataArray count] > 0) {
        [self showPicker:aTextField];
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)aTextField {
    // [self doneClicked:aTextField];
    aTextField.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:  (NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    return NO;
}

-(void) setData:(NSArray*) data
{
    dataArray = data;
    NSLog(@" This is the data : %@ ", dataArray);
}

-(void) showArrowImage:(BOOL)b  
{
    if (b == YES) {
      // set the DownPicker arrow to the right (you can replace it with any 32x24 px transparent image: changing size might give different results)
    self->textField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    }
    else {
        self->textField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
    }
}

-(void) setArrowImage:(UIImage*)image
{
    [(UIImageView*)self->textField.rightView setImage:image];
}

-(void) setPlaceholder:(NSString*)str
{
    self->placeholder = str;
    self->textField.placeholder = self->placeholder;
}

-(void) setPlaceholderWhileSelecting:(NSString*)str
{
    self->placeholderWhileSelecting = str;
}

-(void) setAttributedPlaceholder:(NSAttributedString *)attributedString
{
    self->textField.attributedPlaceholder = attributedString;
}

-(void) setToolbarDoneButtonText:(NSString*)str
{
    self->toolbarDoneButtonText = str;
}

-(void) setToolbarCancelButtonText:(NSString*)str
{
    self->toolbarCancelButtonText = str;
}

-(void) setToolbarStyle:(UIBarStyle)style;
{
    self->toolbarStyle = style;
}

-(UIPickerView*) getPickerView
{
    return self->pickerView;
}

-(UITextField*) getTextField
{
    return self->textField;
}

-(NSString*) getValueAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    return (self->dataArray.count > index) ? [self->dataArray    objectAtIndex:index] : nil;
}

-(void) setValueAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    if (index >= 0) [self pickerView:nil didSelectRow:index inComponent:0];
    else [self setText:nil];
}

/**
 Getter for text property.
 @return
 The value of the selected item or NIL NIL if nothing has been selected yet.
 */
- (NSString*) text {
    return self->textField.text;
}

/**
 Setter for text property.
 @param txt
 The value of the item to select or NIL to clear selection.
 */
- (void) setText:(NSString*)txt {
    if (txt != nil) {
        NSInteger index = [self->dataArray indexOfObject:txt];
        if (index != NSNotFound) [self setValueAtIndex:index];
    }
    else {
        self->textField.text = txt;
    }
}

/**
 Getter for selectedIndex property.
 @return
 The zero-based index of the selected item or -1 if nothing has been selected yet.
 */
- (NSInteger)selectedIndex {
    NSInteger index = [self->dataArray indexOfObject:self->textField.text];
    return (index != NSNotFound) ? (NSInteger)index : -1;
}

/**
 Setter for selectedIndex property.
 @param index
 Sets the zero-based index of the selected item using the setValueAtIndex method:    -1 can be used to clear selection.
 */
- (void)setSelectedIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    [self setValueAtIndex:(NSInteger)index];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your Downpicker is a subclass of UIPickerView, you should implement it`s delegate method named:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component __TVOS_PROHIBITED;
```

which can solve you problem.

Answer (score 0):

First I would like to suggest you to use NSDictionary instead of two arrays: you could set the key of the dictionary as the country short and the value as the phone and use it as:

```
NSString *phoneCode = self.codeDict[@"en"];
```

Second, create a category for DownPicker and override `[pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent]`. And from there you can post the same notification used for the Done action or you can create a protocol for that.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers mentioned, the key here should be in the pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent delegate method.

It appears that you've added it to your RootViewController, but the RootViewController isn't the UIPickerViewDelegate (the subclass of your UIPickerView is).  To rectify this, you'll want to adjust your RootViewController to be the UIPickerViewDelegate and set the instance of your pickerView's delegate to the RootViewController:

> @interface RootViewController : UIViewController

```
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController     <UITextFieldDelegate,UITableViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate>
```

...

Then in viewDidLoad of your rootViewController set the picker view's delegate to self:

```
self.pickerCountry.delegate = self
```